Show that $\vdash (\forall x(C_x\implies M_x)\implies (\exists xC_x\implies \exists xM_x))$

Show that $\vdash (\forall x(C_x\implies M_x)\implies (\exists xC_x\implies \exists xM_x))$

The steps I've taken:
(1) By the deduction rule, it suffices to show:
$$\forall x(C_x\implies M_x)\vdash (\exists xC_x\implies \exists xM_x)$$
(2) Again, By the deduction rule, it suffices to show:
$$\forall x(C_x\implies M_x), \exists xC_x\vdash \exists xM_x$$
(3) Switching quantifiers:
$$\forall x(C_x\implies M_x),(\neg \forall x(\neg C_x))\vdash (\neg \forall x(\neg M_x))$$
According to the assignment directions, I should next use the contrapositive. However, the directions given for the rest of the question seem to suggest that we'd proceed from:
$$\color{red}{ \forall x(\neg M_x) \vdash (\neg \forall x(C_x\implies M_x)),(\forall x(\neg C_x))}$$
As I continued from that point on, I was able to prove the original statement. But this contrapositive doesn't seem right since $\neg (p\wedge q)\not \equiv (\neg p) \wedge (\neg q)$. Shouldn't the actual contrapositive be:
$$\forall x(\neg M_x) \vdash (\neg (\forall x(C_x\implies M_x)\wedge (\neg \forall x(\neg C_x))))$$
How do I proceed using this actual contrapositive to deduce an answer?

Hi. I don't understand what your question is exactly.

I’m not sure where you think $\neg (p \land q) \equiv (\neg p \land \neg q)$ is coming into play, but if you’re confused about commas separating formulas, just know that $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ iff at least one formula in $\Delta$ is true given that all the formulas of $\Gamma$ are true.

@Julián I edited. The red formula is what I originally did and it worked to prove the original statement. The one below it is what I think the actual contrapositive should be and I don't know how to continue from that point.

@PW_246 I've always interpreted the commas to be the equivalent of "$\wedge$" (when they're on the left side of "$\vdash$"). So commas on the right side of "$\vdash$" just means any of the formulas being satisfied is good enough? Is the statement of (3) equivalent to the red statement, then?

@amazinganimal3219 yes, they’re equivalent.

@PW_246 and as an example of what you said about $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$, it is the case that $(C_x\wedge D_x) \vdash C_y, D_x$ since $(C_x\wedge D_x)\vdash D_x$?

Yes, that’s correct.

@PW_246 One last question. Am I allowed to deconstruct $(C_x\wedge D_x)\vdash D_x$ into $C_x, D_x\vdash D_x$? I appreciate your help so much

While it is valid, it depends on which proof system you’re using as to whether or not it’s a valid instance of a rule. I’ve never seen that specific way of doing it; sequent calculus does it in the reverse. I.e., $A,B \vdash C \implies A \land B \vdash C$ is a possible rule in a version of sequent calculus. In Gentzen’s system the $\land$-Left rule is $\Gamma, A \vdash C \implies \Gamma, A \land B \vdash C$. Using this rule and Contraction, you can prove $A \land B \vdash C$ from $A,B \vdash C$.

In a Fitch-style proof under the Cambridge rule set, the process is simple:

| $\forall x(Cx \rightarrow Mx) :: SM(\rightarrow I)$
|| $\exists xCx :: SM(\rightarrow I)$
||| $Ca :: SM(\exists E)$
||| $Ca \rightarrow Ma :: \forall E, 1$
||| $Ma :: \rightarrow E, 4, 3$
||| $\exists xMx :: \exists I, 5$
|| $\exists xMx :: \exists E, 2, 3-6$
| $\exists xCx \rightarrow \exists xMx :: \rightarrow I, 2-7$
$\forall x(Cx \rightarrow Mx) \rightarrow (\exists xCx \rightarrow \exists xMx) :: \rightarrow I, 1-8$

Follow whatever analogous strategy your system allows, and you'll arrive at the same result.
